# How to get a list of all running ros nodes with rosjava?

Tags: java, ros

I am trying to use rosjava to get a list of all running rosnodes. Does anyone know how I could accomplish that? I am new to ros java and unfortunately the documentation is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to get the nodes straight forward. But you could try to use [MasterClient.getSystemState](http://rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/0.0.0/javadoc/org/ros/internal/node/client/MasterClient.html#getSystemState(org.ros.namespace.GraphName)/node/client/MasterClient.html) which returns the state of the ROS graph as understood by the master. It contains all topics in the system state. You could iterate all publishers and subscribers of these topics to get all nodes.

Here is an untested snippet which should allow to get the topics with their publisher and subscribers.

```
MasterClient masterClient = MasterClient(masterUri);
Response<SystemState> systemState = masterClient.getSystemState(GraphName.of("WHATEVER"));
Collection<TopicSystemState> topicList = systemState.getResult().getTopics();
for (String topic : topicList) {
    Set<String> publishers = topic.getPublishers();
    for (String publisher : publishers) {
        System.out.println(publisher);
    }
    Set<String> subscribers = topic.getSubscribers();
    for (String subscriber : subscribers) {
        System.out.println(subscriber);
    }
}
```

After getting all topics, you could collect all nodes by iterating the available publishers and subscribers for each topic.